# Nested function as method in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I'm trying hard to understand basic concepts of javascript. The code below seems to be working fine if I use only "gear += 1" in line 8 below, but I cannot understand why is this not working when I'm using "this.gear += 1". It gives result as NaN. Thank you.

```
(function bike(speed, tank, gear) {
  var i = {};
  i.speed = speed;
  i.tank = tank;
  i.gear = gear;
  i.addgear = (function() { 
    // works fine with "return gear+= 1" Why not with "this"?     
    return this.gear += 1;  
 })();

 console.log("mybike", i);   
})(120, 12, 5);
```

Comment: Why do you expect `this` to work in the first place? None of this looks class-y (including pre-ES5 JS OOP), so I'm not quite sure what to explain.

Comment: Your closure for i.addgear is executing immediately.

Comment: @EthanKaminski - actually, it makes perfect sense for `addgear`'s `this` to be `i`... except that the OP is, perhaps unintentionally, assigning the result of an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to `addgear` rather than an anonymous function.

Comment: @JDB - Yes, that was exactly my point. addgear's this should act as i... but it doesn't... Can you tell why?

Comment: @Rohit - Geuis already told you. Read that article I linked to in my comment. Your assigning the result of executing the function, rather than the actual function. You're very close to a working solution, you're just overdoing it: `i.addgear = (function() { 
    // works fine with "return gear+= 1" Why not with "this"?     
    return this.gear += 1;  
 });` <-- remove the extra `()`.

Comment: For those voting that this was a duplicate of the standard "how does `this` work" post... that wasn't what this question asked, not directly, nor does the answer there really help explain either what's wrong with the code supplied or how to get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you're looking for, including the [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) keyword from ES2015 and up or the prototype system that underlies it.  Here's a very simple sample:

```js
function bike(speed, tank, gear) {
  return {speed, tank, gear, addGear: function() {return this.gear += 1}}
}

const myBike = bike(120, 12, 5)
console.log(myBike);
myBike.addGear();
console.log(myBike)
```

Yours doesn't work for several reasons.  First of all, you never return anything out of your outermost function.  Secondly, you create and immediately execute a function whose **output** then becomes your `addGear` value.  The simplest fix to your code would be something like this:

```
function bike(speed, tank, gear) {
  var i = {};
  i.speed = speed;
  i.tank = tank;
  i.gear = gear;
  i.addgear = function() { 
    return this.gear += 1;  
  };
  return i;
}
```

That would be equivalent to what I wrote above.